# panel overlapping  while loading them dynamically sencha

Tags: forms, extjs, panel

I have several tabs on toolbar each of them having seperate handler , i have called seperate function of each handler . The code is as below

```
Ext.define('myco.view.User', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    config: {
        scrollable: true,
        items: [{
                xtype: 'panel',
                id: 'User'
            },

            {
            docked: 'top',
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            items: [{
                text: 'My Profile',
                handler: function() {
                    var panel = Ext.getCmp('User'),
                        tpl = new Ext.XTemplate([
                        '<div class="demo-weather">',
                            '<tpl for=".">',
                                '<div class="day">',
                                    '<div class="date">{username}</div>',
                                    '<tpl for="weatherIconUrl">',
                                        '<img src="{value}">',
                                    '</tpl>',
                                    '<span class="temp">{tempMaxF}&deg;<span class="temp_low">{tempMinF}&deg;</span></span>',
                                '</div>',
                            '</tpl>',
                        '</div>'
                    ]);

                    panel.getParent().setMasked({
                        xtype: 'loadmask',
                        message: 'Loading...'
                    });

                    Ext.Ajax.request({
                        url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/myapp/user/',
                        method:'GET',
                        callbackKey: 'callback',
                        defaultHeaders : 'application/json',
                        params: {
                            //key: '23f6a0ab24185952101705',
                            //q: '94301', // Palo Alto
                            format: 'json',
                            //num_of_days: 5
                        },
                        success : function(response, opt) {
                                    dataarray = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                                    weather=dataarray.objects;
                                    panel.updateHtml(tpl.applyTemplate(weather))
                                    panel.getParent().unmask();
                                    },
                        failure : function(response, opt) {
                                     Ext.Msg.alert('Failed', response.responseText);
                                     panel.getParent().unmask();
                                    }       


                    });
                }
            },
            {
                 text:'login',
                 handler: function() {
                     var main = new Ext.Panel({  
                                   title: 'My first panel', //panel's title  
                                   fullscreen: true,
                                   //the element where the panel is going to be inserted 
                                   //html: 'Nothing important just dummy text' //panel's content  
                                   items:[
                        {
                            xtype: 'fieldset',
                            title: 'Login',
                            items: [
                                {
                                    xtype: 'textfield',
                                    label: 'Username',
                                    name:   'username',
                                    id  :  'username'
                                },
                                {
                                    xtype: 'passwordfield',
                                    label: 'Password',
                                    name:  'password',
                                    id   :  'password'
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            text: 'Send',
                            ui: 'confirm',

                            handler: function() {}

                        }
                    ]
                                   });  
                 panel.add(main);
                 alert('test');
                 }
            }
            ]
        }]
    }
});
```

Now when i click on the tab , previous panel will not be cleared and data will get overlapped there ..... like when i click My profile profile is listed there , after that when i click login  profile+ login both will be loaded one overlapping another ...

Comment: So you want to run your 'My Profile' handler when the 'login' item is clicked?

Comment: no . i want to display login form when login item is clicked

Comment: where is your login form defined? Provide more details...

Comment: So what is your problem again? Your code seems to do what you've described

Comment: please check the edited question, as i am facing minor issue now... how to clear panel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Ext.tab.Panel](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel) for this, define your profile and login panels as items of a parent TabPanel, the switching will be handled by ExtJS. You can use the *activate* event of a Panel to add custom logic to execute when your tabs get activated.